# How can i stop my mobile application from accessing internet network when my application is starting?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am using adobe dreamweaver in developing mobile application and my intention is to develop an offline application no internet access is required. 
But i am done with the development and i installed this app on my phone but when network data is off my app will run on offline properly.
But problem comes in when network data is on it will it will try to go online it will report
android_asset/www not found error

So please how can i stop my my mobile app from accessing network on starting?

Comment: While launching your activity, just turn off wifi using code.

Comment: but this is not a good way, Why you need such type of scenario. Can you please explain so that we can provide/think any other way.

Comment: Do not add internet permissions in your app and the app would never try to access internet. If it does, you would get a crash and you can act on it during your testing phase

Comment: @Ankur Aggarwal And Amit thanks for your contribution. how can i remove internet permission in my app is it through coding or as a user? please give me a little hint(example) thanks